# Proving $\alpha x^\alpha \leq \frac{y^{\alpha} - x^{\alpha}}{log(\frac{y}{x})} \leq \alpha y^{\alpha}$

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

I've read in my book that the following holds for $0 < x <y$ and $\alpha > 0$ and it does (when I use different numbers), but how can one prove this formally?

$\alpha x^\alpha \leq \frac{y^{\alpha} - x^{\alpha}}{log(\frac{y}{x})} \leq \alpha y^{\alpha}$

I would have taken arbitrary constants and then shown that the equation holds, but I think it's the wrong approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

It is a consequence of the [generalized mean value theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysMean-ValueTheorem.html):

- $\frac{y^{\alpha} - x^{\alpha}}{\log y - \log x} = \frac{\alpha\eta^{\alpha-1}}{\frac{1}{\eta}} = \alpha\eta^{\alpha}$ for some $\eta$ with $x < \eta <y$